# Using NMinimize to solve the Multi Commodity Flow problem

Tags: equation-solving, graphs-and-networks, mathematical-optimization, vector-calculus

I have the following optimization problem and I was hoping to solve it with NMinimize. Unfortunately, I don't get the desired result. I would like to get an optimal vector for $d_{e}$.

This is how the optimization problem looks like.
\begin{aligned}
& \underset{d}{\text{minimize}}
& &g(y_{e}) =\sum_{e=1}^{E}\frac{\phi(y_{e},c_{e})}{c_{e}} \\
& \text{subject to}
&& \\
&\
& & H_{k,r}\,\,  \vec{d_{r}} = \vec{f_{k}} \
&&&(1)\\
& \
& & L_{e,r\,\,}  \vec{d_{r}} = \vec{y_{e}}  \
&&&(2)\\
& \
& & \vec{d_{r}}\geq 0 \
&&&(3)\\
& \
&& y_{e} \geq 0
&&&(4)\\
\end{aligned}

The tricky thing is that $\phi(y_{e},c_{e})$ has to be substituted for constraint 2 to minimize for d. Further, $\phi(y_{e},c_{e})$ is a vector that expresses a piece-wise linear function for all links in the network. Further, $H_{k,r}$ and $L_{e,r\,\,}$ are matrices, which you can see if you execute my sample code. 
This is my sample code:

```
 (*------------------------------------------------------------*)     
(*-Function 0: generateBarabasiAlbertGraph--------------------*)
(*------------------------------------------------------------*)  

generateBarabasiAlbertGraph[n_, k_] /; n >= 3 :=
  Module[{g = CycleGraph[3], vc, vl, el},
   Do[vc = VertexCount[g]; vl = VertexList[g];
    (* Maps a new undirected edge from the new vertex = 
    vc +1 to the vertex obtained from the random sample of the Vertex \
Degrees    *)
    el = Map[UndirectedEdge[vc + 1, #] &,  
      RandomSample[VertexDegree[g] -> vl, Min[k, vc]]];
    (* generates a new graph by joing the edgeList of the previous \
graph with the new  *)
    g = Graph[Join[EdgeList[g], el], 
      VertexLabels -> Placed["Name", Before]],
    {n - 3}];
   g
   ];

v = RandomInteger[{4, 4}];
l = RandomInteger[{1, 2}];
g = generateBarabasiAlbertGraph[v, l];  
g = DirectedGraph[g]; 
vc = VertexCount[g];
vertices = VertexList[g];
edges = EdgeList[g];
ec = EdgeCount[g];
vertexpairs = Permutations[vertices, {2}];
mdg = RandomInteger[{0, 10}, {vc, vc}];



paths = FindPath[g, Sequence @@ #, Infinity, All] & /@ vertexpairs;
paths = Flatten[paths, 1];
L = Outer[
   Sort /@ Boole@MemberQ[DirectedEdge @@@ Partition[#2, 2, 1], #1] &, 
   edges, paths, 1];
Subscript[f, k] = 
  Partition[Part[mdg, Sequence @@ #] & /@ vertexpairs, 1];
H = Outer[Boole[#1 == #2[[{1, -1}]]] &, vertexpairs, paths, 1];
Subscript[z, e] = Subscript[y, c] = 
   Piecewise[{{y, 0 <= y/# <= 1/3}, {3 y - (2/3) #, 
        1/3 <= y/# <= 2/3}, {10 y - (16/3) #, 
        2/3 <= y/# <= 9/10}, {70 y - (178/3) #, 
        9/10 <= y/# <= 1}, {70 y - (178/3) #, 
        9/10 <= y/# <= 1}, {500 y - (1468/3) #, 
        1 <= y/# <= 11/10}, {5000 y - (16318/3) #, 
        11/10 <= y/# <= \[Infinity]}}] & /@ c;
    Print[Plot[#, {y, 0, 1}] & /@ Subscript[z, e]];
    Print[Subscript[z, e]];
    cT = Transpose[{1/c}];

solution = 
  NMinimize[{Sum[Subscript[z, e]/cT, {1, ec}], 
    H. d == Subscript[f, k] && L. d == y && d >= 0 && y >= 0}, {d}];



(*Section. Print results*)
shortestpathlinkTableL = TableForm[L, TableHeadings -> {edges, paths}];
Print["L"];
Print[shortestpathlinkTableL];
 Subscript[grid, 2] = Transpose@{Subscript[f, k]};
 demand = 
  TableForm[Subscript[grid, 2], 
   TableHeadings -> {vertexpairs, {"demand per commocidty \
(\!\(\*SubscriptBox[\(f\), \(k\)]\))", "demand round n"}}];
 Print[demand];
```

Maybe, I am totally wrong by using NMinimize and should rather go for LinearProgramming or any other function.